# IN PLSQL - How to create a function which accepts date as input yyyy-mm--dd and write query inside the function to evaluate whether the date is valid

Tags: oracle, function, date, plsql

How to create a function which accepts date as input `yyyy-mm-dd` and write query inside the function to evaluate whether the date is valid in PL/SQL.

Comment: This function already exists: [`validate_conversion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD)

Comment: Also asked on OTN _ https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4489083/create-a-function-which-accepts-date-as-input-yyyy-mm-dd#latest

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

- accept input parameter (which is a string)
- convert it to `DATE` value (line #6)

  - if it succeeds, return `OK`
  - if not, exception is raised (you don't really care which one; input string just doesn't represent valid date value, represented in format you specified: `yyyy-mm-dd`) and function returns `NOK`

---

```
SQL> create or replace function f_date (par_date in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_date date;
  5  begin
  6    l_date := to_date(par_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  7    return 'OK';
  8  exception
  9    when others then
 10      return 'NOK';
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_date('2021-09-17') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK

SQL> select f_date('2021-19-87') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOK

SQL>
```

Comment: I can't comment **PosgreSQL**'s syntax, @Atishay. pl/pgsql is different from **Oracle**'s PL/SQL. We're talking Oracle here.